# Custom content type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a custom content type create in visual studio 2010:

[custom http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/439/customf.jpg](http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/439/customf.jpg)

Here you have my custom content type....
I would like to use this content type in a sub-site in the same site.
Now I have this:

http // XXXXX/........../Forms/AllItems.aspx

I would like to use this content type in

http //XXXXX/SUBSITE...../Forms/AllItems.aspx...

In the code I associated my custom content type to the first document library like this:

```
 <CustomAction
Id="SPTest.CustomMenuItem.ButtonClicked"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
RegistrationId="{F9658A9F-3F04-48BD-A14A-9EBAF5DE9EE8}"
RegistrationType="List"
>
```

Where RegistrationId is the Id of document's library site, but when I put in this RegistrationId the Id of the subsite document library... nothing happens...

Another Question: *When I selected an item in this document library, Documents tab will be show.... IS there some way to display PATOne Rule Engine instead of documents tab???*

Comment: Can you provide the definition for content type and how it's linked to the document's library.  The custom action just creates widget under a menu item.  What you want is to define a content type and apply that to a list definition. These items are site collection scoped, so they should be available within a site collection

Comment: i think that you mean "custom tab" instead of "custom content type"?

Comment: That's right Alexander.... But When I tried to put the Id of the document libraries subsite... This custom tab doesn't appeared there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a "Custom Action", not a "Custom Content Type". Hint: the Content Type will contain a 'ContentType' element. It will look something like:

```
<ContentType ID="0x01AB"
     Name="MyCustomContentType"
     Group="MyCustomContentTypeGroup"
     Description="Customized Content Type"
     Version="0">
   <FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef ID="{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}"
     Name="Created"
     DisplayName="Field1" />
    <FieldRef ID="{1df5e554-ec7e-46a6-901d-d85a3881cb18}"
     Name="Author"
     DisplayName="Field2" />
   </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
```

Further, the RegistrationId should not be a guid if it is to be registered against a content type. If Registered against a list, the RegistrationId should either be the list's type ID e.g. (101 for document libraries in the site), or possibly the GUID of a *specific* list (in which case the action will only work for that list). I've not tried this last one, but suspect it'd work. (**Edit**: It is described as working this way at the bottom of [this discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010programming/thread/1efd3cf1-e978-4020-9a63-929d7b44a3e4))

Depending on what the guid is, you may have registered the custom action for a specific list, but the list in your subsite will have a different ID, so that custom action registration will not apply to it.

In short, you can add custom actions to:

- A specific List, which is what I think you've done.
- All lists of a given type within a site/subsite
- [A content type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768562%28v=office.12%29.aspx) that you then use on those lists. (I've not tried)

To register against a content type, I would expect the registration to look like:

```
<CustomAction 
    Id="SPTest.CustomMenuItem.ButtonClicked"              
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
    RegistrationType="ContentType"
    RegistrationId="0x01AB"
```

Note the RegistrationType and RegistrationId

Comment: Yes I assign my custom action in only one list in a main site, but untill now.... I can't do it for a sub-site...

Answer (score 0):

This is my content type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction
Id="SPTest.CustomMenuItem.ButtonClicked"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
RegistrationId="{F9658A9F-3F04-48BD-A14A-9EBAF5DE9EE8}"
RegistrationType="List"
>
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition
      Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">
      <Tab
        Id="Ribbon.PATOneRule"
        Title="PATOne Rule Engine"
        Sequence="501">
        <Scaling
          Id="Ribbon.PATOneRule.Scaling">
          <MaxSize
            Id="Ribbon.PATOneRule.MaxSize"
            GroupId="Ribbon.PATOneRule.PATOneRuleGroup"
            Size="OneLargeTwoMedium"/>
          <Scale
            Id="Ribbon.PATOneRule.Scaling.PATOneRuleScaling"
            GroupId="Ribbon.PATOneRule.PATOneRuleGroup"
            Size="OneLargeTwoMedium" />
        </Scaling>
        <Groups Id="Ribbon.PATOneRule.Groups">
          <Group
            Id="Ribbon.PATOneRule.PATOneRuleGroup"
            Description="Workflow Rules"
            Title="Workflow Group"
            Sequence="52"
            Template="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplateExample">
            <Controls Id="Ribbon.PATOneRule.PATOneRuleGroup.Controls">
              <Button
                Id="Ribbon.PATOneRule.PATOneRuleGroup.NewWorkflow"
                Image32by32="/PublishingImages/_t/new_jpg.jpg"
                Command="PATOneRule.NewWorkflow"
                Sequence="15"
                Description="Create New Workflow"
                LabelText="New Workflow"
                TemplateAlias="cust1"/>
              <Button
                Id="Ribbon.PATOneRule.PATOneRuleGroup.RunWorkflow"
                Image32by32="/PublishingImages/_t/play_jpg.jpg"
                Command="PATOneRule.RunWorkflow"
                Sequence="15"
                Description="Run Selected Workflow"
                LabelText="Run Workflow"
                TemplateAlias="cust2"/>
              <Button
               Id="Ribbon.PATOneRule.PATOneRuleGroup.EditWorkflow"
               Image32by32="/PublishingImages/_t/edit_jpg.jpg"
               Command="PATOneRule.EditWorkflow"
               Sequence="15"
               Description="Edit Selected Workflow"
               LabelText="Edit Workflow"
               TemplateAlias="cust3"/>
            </Controls>
          </Group>
        </Groups>
      </Tab>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
      <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplateExample">
        <Layout
          Title="OneLargeTwoMedium"
          LayoutTitle="OneLargeTwoMedium">
          <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
            <Row>
              <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust1" />
              <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust3" />
              <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust2" />
            </Row>
          </Section>
        </Layout>
      </GroupTemplate>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="PATOneRule.NewWorkflow"
      CommandAction="javascript:__doPostBack('NewWorkflow', '')" />
    <CommandUIHandler
     Command="PATOneRule.EditWorkflow"
     CommandAction="javascript: 
     function getId() { 
       var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
       var key;
       var itemsSelected;
       for (key in selectedItems) {
       itemsSelected = itemsSelected + ', ' + selectedItems[key].id;
      } 
      __doPostBack('EditWorkflow',itemsSelected); 
     }
     getId();"
     EnabledScript="javascript:
     function singleEnable() { 
       var items = 
       SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(); 
       var ci = CountDictionary(items); 
       return (ci == 1); 
     } 
     singleEnable();"
     />
    <CommandUIHandler
    Command="PATOneRule.RunWorkflow"
    CommandAction="javascript: 
     function getId() { 
       var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
       var key;
       var itemsSelected;
       for (key in selectedItems) {
       itemsSelected = itemsSelected + ', ' + selectedItems[key].id;
      } 
      __doPostBack('RunWorkflow',itemsSelected); 
     }
     getId();"
    EnabledScript="javascript:
     function singleEnable() { 
       var items = 
       SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(); 
       var ci = CountDictionary(items); 
       return (ci>0); 
     } 
     singleEnable();"
     />
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```